# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver… (intellij, gradle)

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea, jdbc

I want to connect to SQL Server by java, Intellij, i add repository in .gradle file like this:

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.2.2.jre7'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.2.2.jre8'
```

Libraries was downloaded successfully, so i could see jar files in project external libraries path:
[image]

After that, i try to connect by follow code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://IpAddress:1433;databaseName=DbName";
        String username = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
```

And i got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I'm surprised because this code works in Eclipse with the same jar file, but not in intellij!

Comment: You added that dependency in `testCompile` scope so it will only be available on the classapth for test classes. Did you invoke `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` from a class in your test tree? Or in your main tree?

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. Are you using this code in a test, or in production code? IntelliJ (and Gradle) have a separate classpath for tests.

Comment: Thanks! when i change it to compile every things works.